# Why does my css text show when my react renders my component page?

Tags: css, reactjs

My css text shows up in my page for some reason. I am wondering if it has to do with importing the css? I cut out some of the code in the jsx.
I have configured webpack to use css.

[page with css showing, css showing as text attribute with text id in css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPWsE.png)
[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/style.css';
import profile_pic from '../res/img_profile_pic.png';

    class Manager_Home extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
             <div classname="Mainpage">
        <div className="sidenav">
                <img src={profile_pic} ></img>
                <p>John Smith</p>
                <p>Manager</p>
                <hr></hr>
                <a href="/home">Home</a>
                <a href="/createSurvey">Create Survey</a>
                <a href="/givenSurveys">Given Surveys</a>  
        </div>
        
        <div className="main">
            <h2>Your Surveys</h2>
            <p class="borders">Survey 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Manager_Home;
```

Comment: You didn't close the div tag after <p>John Smith</p>. What happens when you fix that?

Comment: Maybe try create-react-app, you need nodejs and npm or yarn

Comment: @radihuq Sorry I had that I just didn't put in everything.

Comment: @HMR This is using create-react-app, I ran this through their start-react-script,

Comment: You did `npm start`?

Comment: @HMR yea I did, I feel this may just be a simple mistake somewhere, but couldn't find anyone else who had this silly issue. How could the css text be showing up in the page? Very strange

Comment: What does your package.json look like?

Comment: @HMR here are my dependencies, I am using chrome dev tools to see what attribute the css text is showing up as

 "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start"
  },

Comment: @HMR the head is showing the css in style as text, do you think its something related to a dependency I don't have not rendering it correctly? Not sure where its adding it

Comment: I was thinking an old version of react-scripts maybe because the code posted should work with current react-scripts. You also get no build errors when running npm start?

Comment: Yea it has no build errors, sorry I realized I did not start with create-react-app, I had to add webpack, babel and used npm install — save-dev react-scripts
to set up react, I might have missed something and its causing this?

Comment: @HMR Thanks for your help, I am still not sure why the text showed but I just removed the display css property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by taking out   display: block in the css. I am not sure why it caused the css text to show it up though.